# find files unique to different paths BASH

Tags: bash

I have a suspicion that a few years ago someone accidentally copied a folder structure from `/home/data` to `/home/something/data`.   Since then `/home/data` has had many updates and changes.
What is the easiest way to check if there are any files in `/home/something/data` unique
(by name and location) to that location, to help me confirm if everything in there was a copy from `/home/data`?

Answer (score 2):

Using `diff -r dir1 dir2`, you can recursively scan directories for differences in structure and content. Additional flags can tweak the output and behavior to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rsync` in dry-run mode to see if copying `/home/something/data` into `/home/data` would actually copy any data.

```
 rsync -r --dry-run /home/something/data /home/data
```

If a file under `/home/something/data` is identical to a file under `/home/data`, it would not be copied, and `rsync --dry-run` will not report it.

Answer (score 2):

You may or may not like this approach, it can take a while to scan all files but I generally have a good feeling when I do it.

Go to the top of each directory structure and run a `find` and get the md5 checksums of each and every file - your switches may vary as I am on OSX

```
cd /home/data
find . -type f -exec md5 -r {} + > /tmp/a

cd /home/something/data
find . -type f -exec md5 -r {} + > /tmp/b
```

When they are finished, run the output files through `sort` and `uniq -u` to tell you the lines that only appear once (they should all appear twice if the files are the same in both directories):

```
sort < /tmp/[ab] | uniq -u
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated, but oh so clever! +1! I think it would be more readable with `xargs`

Comment: This is perfect for when the files have been moved around. Thanks.